# Files missing in GUI after recursive chmod or chown

Tags: files, filesystems, gui, chmod, chown

I was trying to set permissions on all of the files in a removable hard disk. I had tried `chown` and `chmod` on the disk address (i.e. /dev/sdb) but I still couldn't move files as a user. Then I tried to recursively set permissions and ownership on all files on the disk with

`sudo chmod -R 666 /media/jdh/b041de7c-7698-44ae-a387-482ab9e60201/`

and

`sudo chown -R jdh /media/jdh/b041de7c-7698-44ae-a387-482ab9e60201/`

Then when I checked the GUI if found all of the directories contained no files and all of the files were 0 bytes in size. To be sure I checked ran `ls` and found all of the files present and of reasonable size.

I don't know how the removable disk is formatted.

What has happened? How can I make the files visible in the GUI again?

Comment: You are missing the execute permissions on directories, so you will not be able to open/view them. Are you using root user to view them or the jdh user? What are you trying to accomplish? Why not set them with 775 instead?

Comment: I'm just trying to move the files with user the user account. I didn't realize that files had to be executable to be viewable in the file manager. I'm not trying to open them I just want to see that they are there.

Comment: I ran the commands using 775 instead and I can see the files once more. Thank you

Comment: Would it be impolite of me to write an answer to this question using the information you provided me?

Comment: Not at all, go ahead!

Comment: also you can recursively copy files, whilst preserving permissions with `cp -rp`

Answer (score 0):

If a directory is not executable then it cannot be opened. `chmod 666` removes execute privileges. If you use a different command like `chmod 775` or `chmod 777` then you will be able to see inside the directory again since they restore execute privileges.