# Why do files become 'invisible' when execution permissions are revoked?

Tags: files, permissions, gui, chmod, thunar

This is somewhat related to my, now resolved, question here [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/572290/files-missing-in-gui-after-recursive-chmod-or-chown). When I ran `chmod 666` on group of files they stopped showing up in the GUI (thunar) but I could see them when I ran `ls`. When I found out that this was because of execution privileges I ran `chmod 775` instead and now I can see them again. I could only see the top level directories and files and the files were 0 bytes in size. Why did this happen?

Comment: Just `ls` or `sudo ls`? If you remove the execute permission from a directory, you can't access it anymore, and it looks like you ran it recursively on a directory.

Comment: @muru it may have been sudo ls, I don't remember

Comment: Isn't this the same question as [your other one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/572290/100397), just phrased differently?

Comment: @muru yes it does answer my question. What's the protocol here, do I delete my post?

Comment: @roaima I wanted to know why it happened not just how to fix it. But I see your point should I delete this post?

Comment: I think your question could be valid, but you would probably need to include information on what "GUI" you are referring to (I assume you mean the file manager, often `nautilus` or similar). The behaviour of showing the files as "0 bytes" is definitely not reasonable ...

Comment: @AdminBee OK I've done that

Comment: 666 removes the "execute" rights on directories, but not the "read" rights. A plain `ls` only needs read rights (it just reads the directory inode), while thunar or `ls` with options to list file parameters  (size, flags...) need to access each file inode, which requires traversal of the directory, which requires "execute" rights on the directory.

Comment: The GUI shows only executable fikes to run...